# Deleting graphics

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to delete all the graphics on a group box when pressing a button, but I cannot figure it out how. Adding a new background to the group box seems slow, I want to make it faster.

Moreover, I've read about the Invalidate() method, but it doesn't  do what I need.

The piece of code I am talking about :

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groupBox0.Invalidate();
    }

    private void groupBox0_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics graphObj = groupBox0.CreateGraphics();

        Pen mypen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 2);

        graphObj.DrawRectangle(mypen, 0, 0, 10, 10);
    }
```

When I run the code it does nothing, the graphics are still there. What can I do or change ?

Comment: `groupBox0.Refresh();`

Comment: also use `e.Graphics` instead of `CreateGraphics`.

Comment: Also put `mypen` in a using statement.

Comment: What "graphics" are you trying to remove? If you mean the red rectangle you are drawing inside the `Paint` event, in addition to other comments make sure you have a form level flag or something to control whether the rectangle should be drawn or not.

Comment: What do you mean by using statement ? And yes, I am referring to the read rectangle in the Paint event.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "delete all graphics".

Comment: Everything I have drawn in the Paint event.

Comment: Pen is disposable, so you should be disposing of it with a using statement.

Comment: You need a flag that when you dont want the red rect the code simply doesnt draw it. ...plus the comments about the Pen and CreateGraphics

Comment: Do not use `CreateGraphics`! Ever! The `Paint` event has `e.Graphics`. If you use this your problems go away..